# How to make onclick do something different the third time?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I searched around stack overflow and all of them only explain how onclick would do something different the second time - but I want my code to do something different the third time too. Here's part of the current javascript:

```
function one()
{
var newButton1 = '<button id="btnTwo" onclick="two();stickAmount();" >Pick up stick</button>'; var newButton2 = '<button id="btnThree" onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick."+newButton1+newButton2;

var myButton = document.getElementById('btnOne');
myButton.onclick = four;
}
```

My guess is that I should do something like the var myButton code near the bottom, but if I try that it only does the third action and skips the second.

Comment: Just store a counter somewhere.  Increment it when you click.  Add whatever logic you want, depending on the counter value.

Comment: Which button receives the 3 clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter isn't what I needed -

Turns out I started out doing the right thing, but the myButton variable wasn't supposed to appear twice in the same function, I had to add the myButton variable to function four.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a static varible in your function?

Comment: There are no static variables in JavaScript.

Comment: I attached link to alternative way.. but same idea

Comment: Now I understand your point, but I wouldn't call those static variables, because they are just data members of an object. Yes, they can be used similarly to static variables in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a counter to your button:

html:

```
<button id="btnOne" data-counter="0" onclick="one();" >Do It</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('btnOne');

function one() {
    var counter=parseInt(myButton.getAttribute("data-counter"),10);
    counter++;
    myButton.setAttribute("data-counter",counter);
    // do something based on the value of counter
}
```